# How can I do vector operations to pointers (instead of int/float) in Neon Intrinsics?

Tags: c++, neon

I have the following code:

```
// int8_t* dout[4];
uint32x4_t ones = vdupq_n_u32(1);
uint32x4_t addr = vaddq_u32(vld1q_u32((uint32_t*)dout), ones);
vst1q_u32((uint32_t*)dout, addr);
```

where `dout[4]` is an array that stores four `(int8_t*)` pointers.

The thing I want to do is, add one to each of the pointers. And I know that a pointer should take up 32 bits in my ARM machine. So I use `vaddq_u32()` to add 1 to the four pointers at one time. However, this code seems not to work properly.

So, what is the standard way of doing vector operations to pointers? Is there anyone who is familiar with ARM Neon Intrinsics? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess this to work (in practice). However, it is probably undefined behaviour so the optimizer might break it unpredictably. What does the code actually do?

Comment: How many pointers do you want to do operate on? If it's more than a dozen, the algorithm design is completely flawed, and it's fully pointless otherwise due to pipeline hazard when moving data from SIMD to integer registers (even via memory). Nobody sane would even consider modifying pointers via Neon on ARM. Hence there is no "standard way of doing vector operations to pointers".

Comment: I would not do that for reasons already mentioned in the comments. However, have you tried to mark the pointer array as volatile? It is possible that the compiler generates code that does not re-read the pointers after changing them.